# Silverlight MediaElement Source Title

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I'm using a MediaElement with this source:

http://origin-community.ministryofsound.com/asx/radio/mosRadio.asx

When I open it with Windows Media Player I get a title: "Ministry of Sound Radio", but I've seen the MediaElement properties and can't find this title.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Pretty pretty good source :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored in the Attributes of the MediaElemet, which are available in the MediaOpened event and after that. Looking at the attributes for your provided source, the key name is "TITLE".

```
    void MyMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb1.Text = (sender as MediaElement).Attributes["TITLE"];
    }
```

Comment: Ah... I was looking inside the object before the open event... Thank you Jeff!

Comment: It doesn't work for sources like this: mms://195.245.168.21/antena3
Do you know what can be the problem? The attributes are empty. 

Thanks in advance.